# Haskell non-exhaustive patterns and converting function output

Tags: haskell

I have a function that wants to list all of a `dataType`.

```
fn [] = []
fn (dt@(DataType t d y [(f,r)]):dts) = ["T:" ++ t ++ " D: " ++ d ++ " R: " ++ show y ++ "Ra" ++ show (fnAvg dt)] ++ fn dts
```

Where t and d are strings, y is an int, f is a string and r is an int (not sure f and r matter though, will explain furthur on).

I got the error non-exhaustive patterns, and presumed it was because I didn't have one for when there was only one element in the list, so I added this between the other patterns:

```
fn [dt@(DataType t d y [(f,r)])] = ["T:" ++ t ++ " D: " ++ d ++ " R: " ++ show y ++ "Ra" ++ show (fnAvg dt)]
```

It compiled, but when I called the function it once again told me 'non-exhaustive patterns'. I'm struggling to think of what pattern i've missed, should I add a wildcard pattern afterward to catch everything? I'm not looking for someone to type out the answer, but hints or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why should the list specified as [(f,r)] only contain one element?

Comment: Good point, hadn't noticed that. Considering the contents of that list don't have relevance to this particular function, could replacing it with [_] be a reasonable solution?

Comment: @Chillo If you don't need it on the right-hand side, then yes, that'll work.

Comment: It came up with an error, but the issue has been solved! I added a line with ((f,r):rs) and it works fine. Although they go unused it works, thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, you can replace a load of `++`s with a single `concat` and a list - it may be bit easier to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do already cover the one-element-list case: that matches `fn (dt@(DataType t d y [(f,r)]):[])`, since `dts` can be anything including the empty list.

Indeed there's no reason to use explicit recursion here: you basically have something like

```
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = g x ++ f xs
```

Compare that to the monad instance of lists:

```
instance Monad [] where
  return x = [x]
  [] >>= _ = []
  (x:xs) >>= g = g x ++ (xs >>= g)
```

So you should write you function as

```
fn l = l >>= \dt@( DataType t d y [(f,r)] ) 
    -> ["T:" ++ t ++ " D: " ++ d ++ " R: " ++ show y ++ "Ra" ++ show (fnAvg dt)]
```

That won't fix your problem though, but it makes it obvious what's going on: evidently, `DataType t d y [(f,r)]` is not the only valid pattern for that type. As MathematicalOrchid points out, `[(f,r)]` matches only a list with length 1, but you need to cover other lengths as well.

```
fn l = l >>= \dt -> case dt of
   DataType t d y [(f,r)]
    -> ["T:" ++ t ++ " D: " ++ d ++ " R: " ++ show y ++ "Ra" ++ show (fnAvg dt)]
   DataType t d y []
    -> ["Some other stuff"]
   DataType t d y [(f,r), ...]
    -> ["Yet other stuff"]
```

or whatever.

Indeed, if you only ever return `[ ("stuff") ]` here, then you're not really using the monadic bind functionality at all: you could have written the recursive version without `++`, only reconstruct the thing with `:`, and in fact you have simply a `map` operation:

```
fn = map $ \dt -> case dt of
   DataType t d y [(f,r)]
    -> "T:" ++ t ++ " D: " ++ d ++ " R: " ++ show y ++ "Ra" ++ show (fnAvg dt)
   DataType t d y []
    -> "Some other stuff"
   DataType t d y [(f,r), ...]
    -> "Yet other stuff"
```

Comment: Very helpful to me in finding the right way to fix my problem, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

The pattern `[(f,r)]` only matches when the list contains *one* element. If it contains zero, or two, or *any other number*, you have a pattern match failure.

What the code should *do* in this instance, I couldn't say...

Comment: The code tries the argument to `fn` against several different patterns, but the last argument to `DataType` is _always_ `[(f,r)]`, which only matches a one-element list.

Comment: Fixed making it ((f,r):rs) which seems to work suitably even if they aren't used variables. Thank you!